# Can a problem be solved if value of $z$ is not given?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Can a problem like the following be solved with Cramer's rule?

$\left\{\begin{array}{l}
&8x+6y-3z=42\\
&3x-6y+z=18\\
&4x-3y-12=0\\
\end{array}\right.$

In this problem $z$ is not given for the 3rd equation.

Can a such problem be solved in this case? How?

Comment: What is the two stars ** ?

Comment: I edited it sorry

Comment: Just do as if there were $\ldots +0\cdot z$.

Comment: We can rewrite the last equation as $4x-3y+0z-12=0.$ Does that answer your question?

Comment: Oh OK, yes it does answer my question

Comment: using subtraction or addition of the first and last in theory you can solve for z and get it out of the way anyways potentially.

Comment: If the problem is actually written in columns like that, maybe $4x-3y-12=0$ was a misprint for $4x-3y-12z=0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you do the same: the term $0z  $ is implicit.